# Bubble sort variant - three adjacent number swapping

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This problem appeared in code jam 2018 qualification round which has ended.
https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/ (Problem 2)

Problem description:

> The basic operation of the standard bubble sort algorithm is to examine a pair of adjacent numbers and reverse that pair if the left number is larger than the right number. But our algorithm examines a group of three adjacent numbers, and if the leftmost number is larger than the rightmost number, it reverses that entire group. Because our algorithm is a "triplet bubble sort", we have named it Trouble Sort for short.
>
> We were looking forward to presenting Trouble Sort at the Special
>   Interest Group in Sorting conference in Hawaii, but one of our interns
>   has just pointed out a problem: it is possible that Trouble Sort does
>   not correctly sort the list! Consider the list 8 9 7, for example.
>
> We need your help with some further research. Given a list of N
>   integers, determine whether Trouble Sort will successfully sort the
>   list into non-decreasing order. If it will not, find the index
>   (counting starting from 0) of the first sorting error after the
>   algorithm has finished: that is, the first value that is larger than
>   the value that comes directly after it when the algorithm is done.

So a naive approach will be to apply trouble sort on the given list, apply normal sort on the list, and find the index of the first non-matching element. However, this would time out for very large N.

Here is what I figured:
The algorithm will compare 0th index with 2nd, 2nd with 4th and so on.
Similarly 1st with 3rd, 3rd with 5th and so on.

All the elements at odd index will be sorted with respect to odd index. Same for even indexed element.
So the issue would lie between two consecutive odd/even indexed element.

I can't think of a way to figure it out without doing an O(n^2) approach.

Is my approach any viable, or there is something easier?

Comment: https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/00000000000000cb/analysis/00000000000079cb

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I have no idea how I missed that! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is spot on. The algorithm presented in the problem statement will only compare( and swap ) the consecutive odd and even elements among themselves.

If you take that observation one step further, you can state that Trouble Sort is an algorithm that correctly sorts odd- and even-indexed elements of an array within themselves. (i.e. as if odd-indexed elements and even-indexed elements of an array A are two separate arrays B and C)

In other words, Trouble Sort does sort B and C correctly. The issue here is whether those arrays B and C of odd and even-indexed elements can be merged properly. You should check if sorting odd- and even-indexed elements among themselves is enough to make the entire array sorted.

This step is really similar to the merging step of MergeSort. The only difference is that, due to the indexing being a limiting factor on your operation, you know at all times from which array you will pick the top element. For a 1-indexed array A, during the merging step of B and C, at each step, you should pick the smallest *previously unpicked* element from B, and then C.

So, basically, if you sort B and C, which takes, `O(NlogN)` using an algorithm such as mergesort or heapsort, and then merge them in the manner described in the previous paragraph, which takes `O(N)`, you end up with the same version of the array A after it has been processed by the Trouble Sort algorithm.

The difference is the time complexity. While Trouble Sort takes `O(N^2)` time, the operations described above takes `O(NlogN)` time. Once you end up with this array, then you can check in `O(N)` time if, for each consecutive indices i, j, `A[i] < A[j]` holds. The overall complexity of the algorithm would still be `O(NlogN)`.

Below is a code sample in Python to demonstrate sort of a pseudocode of the algorithm I described above. There are a couple of minor differences in implementation due to Python arrays being 0-indexed. You may observe the execution of this code [here](https://ideone.com/YBxdSa).

```
def does_trouble_sort_work(A):
    B, C = A[0::2], A[1::2]
    B_sorted = sorted(B)
    C_sorted = sorted(C)
    j = k = 0
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            A[i] = B_sorted[j]
            j += 1
        else:
            A[i] = C_sorted[k]
            k += 1 

    trouble_sort_works = True
    for i in xrange(1, len(A)):
        if A[i-1] > A[i]:
            trouble_sort_works = False
            break
    return trouble_sort_works
```

Comment: elegantly described. Thanks!